# Optimizing the print function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, file-io, graphics, save

I maintain a software package that automates ingestion of data.  When raw data is imported, it is plotted and some graphics of the data are saved to disk.  Unfortunately, the `print` function dramatically slows my performance.

Here is a breakdown of the code performance

```
Script       Time
myscript     9.091s
uichoosefile 3.567s
print        4.178s
legend       0.751s
```

Only about 3/4s of my execution time is real processing time and `print` is the biggest timesink here.

Inside `print` two lines take up almost 100% of the time

```
Line Code                                Time
212  pj = pj = alternatePrintPath(pj);   3.173s
148  drawnow;                            0.751s
```

How can I create an optimized version of `print` that isn't bottlenecked by these two lines?  Simple optimization routines such as lowering graphics resolution are not desirable.

Comment: `print` is a large function that does many things. How are you calling it? Please provide example code that demonstrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you need to save the graphics in a raster format (PNG, JPG or however your are exporting them) at this point or can you just save the .fig file with hgsave and postpone this to a later stage?

Comment: @txpaulm unfortunately I don't have the luxury of restricted vector or raster formats.  When data is ingested a config file for the customer is pulled as well that specifies, among other things, the delivery formats for the plots of their data, PNG, PDF, SVG, EPS, etc.  PDF+PNG is the most typical scenario.  Print is very buggy when commands are issued during its execution, so I do not believe postponing the saving is very viable; it may break if e.g. the operator clicks during the save routine.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab is actually rather special in that it is pretty easy to optimize its internal functions. [I did this](https://github.com/kroneckerbio/kroneckerbio/tree/v0.5.0.0/External/ode15sf) to `ode15s` in a [systems biology modelling](https://github.com/kroneckerbio/kroneckerbio) toolbox that I wrote.

This is how you do it yourself:

1. Make a new folder. I'll call it `image_print`.
2. Add that folder to the Matlab path so you can use it anywhere `addpath('image_print')`
3. Copy the function you want to optimize into the new folder `image_print` and give the file a new name. I'll call it `printimage.m`.
4. In the folder where the original function was, there will be a folder called `private`. Copy that folder into your new folder `image_print`. Keep the name as `private`.

Now you can use `printimage` and optimize it without screwing up the rest of Matlab. What actually helps will depend entirely on your actual workflow and require a fair amount of cleverness on your part. You are starting from the right spot by using the profiler. Basically, you'll have to figure out via trial and error what the slow steps are doing and then see if there is a faster way to do it specifically for your work. The original function is very general, so you will be able to cut entire sections out. Don't forget that you can modify the functions in `private` also.

Bonus suggestion: Because you only want save the figures to disk, you might want to focus on preventing them from wasting time actually drawing to the screen. You might be able to comment out the `drawnow` line entirely, but please report back on what actually happens.

Comment: and you call this pretty easy? ....*repeat until all missing functions* ... I think you meant this all as a sarcastic remark I hope

Comment: @percusse Name another language in which it is possible to modify `print` in 10 minutes flat.

Comment: Python, Javascript, R. If you do it in 10 minutes in matlab, I'll start using it again