# How to disable the progress bar when using the nlfilter function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Each time I call the `nlfilter` function a progress bar window appears. How could I disable that window?. Is there an option like `-q`?

I'm processing an image by rows and applying a custom function, so the window generated when calling to the nlfilter function is bothering quite a lot and also decreasing the performance of my system.

Note that I'm only want disable the window momentarily.

Comment: I guess you could comment the relevant lines in the code (lines 64-68) after typing `edit nlfilter` in the Command Window. Then you can uncomment whenever you want.

Comment: @Benoit_11 Good point but Matlab is installed in a directory where I have not write permission and copy the function to my working directory is not the solution I'm looking for :)

Comment: @pQB You can [copy the function to a folder on your path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345739/optimizing-the-print-function-in-matlab/34354095#34354095) to which you have write access. Matlab will use that version instead of the built-inversion.

Comment: From the source code it is clear that the waitbar can not be configured, you have to copy and modify the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `waitbar` within MATLAB definitely reduces the performance of your code as well as gets really obnoxious when running long-running tasks on some operating systems as it can steal the focus of your keyboard/mouse randomly.

I personally create my own `waitbar` function and place it on the MATLAB path so that it is evaluated rather than the built-in.

I have a more complicated text-based progress bar, but the following function will simply print the messages to the command line. You could even remove the first block and have the contents simply be `varargout = {[]};` and you will have no output.

```
function varargout = waitbar(varargin)
    if nargin >= 2 && ischar(varargin{2})
        disp(varargin{2})
    elseif nargin >= 3 && ischar(varargin{3})
        disp(varargin{3})
    end
    varargout = {[]};
end
```

Be sure to save this in `waitbar.m` somewhere high on your MATLAB path.

> **NOTE**: This will silence *all* waitbars so if you want to restore the typical waitbar behavior, you will want to remove/rename this file.